# Polygons created with R are corrupted when imported into ArcMAP

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, r, import

I created some polygons using R and to get a better visualization and some other stuff I need to import those into ArcMap. However, when I imported the polygons I realized there are some holes in some of the polygons,not all. Then I thought there could be a problem with the calculation but when I checked R, there's no problem with the polygons. I'm completely lost about what's wrong. This is my R polygons:[image]

and this is what I got from ArcMap:

[image]

Can you help me understand what's wrong with them?

Comment: What happens if you run `gIsValid(your_polygon, byid=TRUE)` (from maptools) on the polygon feature in R.

Comment: How did you create them and how did you get them into Arc? Your code is needed here

Comment: What does the Check Geometry tool of ArcGIS for Desktop report for your polygons or are they in a format inaccessible to it?

Comment: I suspect your shapefiles were corrupted long before they reached ArcGIS.

Comment: First, thanks everyone for their respond.
Cyrille- I checked as you suggested and they're valid, so no problem with that.
mdsummer- I created my polygons using a long process of codes but for the final part I exported them as ESRI shapefiles and added the shapefile into ArcMAP. It is wierd that it looks fine on R while it doesn't on ArcMAP.

Comment: PolyGeo- I did as you suggested and and it found a problem. Then I used Repair Geometry tool and it worked. Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry I was quick to respond. it solved the problem with the one on the right but the left is still the same. any more suggestions?